# How to hide node webform programatically?

Tags: 7, webforms, nodes

[image]

I want to make hide WEBFORM  particular content type programmatically in default / custom mode.
Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it after checking field module in core.

```
$bundle_settings = field_bundle_settings('node', $bundle);
  $viewmode = 'custom';
  $name = 'webform';
  $bundle_settings['extra_fields']['display']['webform']['custom'] = array(
    'weight' => 1,
    'visible' => TRUE / FALSE,
  );
  field_bundle_settings('node', $bundle, $bundle_settings);
```

This will enable/disable field in specified view mode

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).Then you can put your condition on `$node->type`, access the webform with `$node->webform` and use `$view_mode` to load the current view mode.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom module disable it with :

```
function yourmodule_node_view($node, $view_mode){
    // if you want exclude you content type
    if($node->type =='yourcontenttype' && $view_mode=='yourdesireviewmode'){
    $node->content['webform']['enabled'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

for more details take look at [hook_node_view](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and  [webform_node_view](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.module/function/webform_node_view/7).

Answer (score 0):

This handy module will do it as well and will give you some nice config options: https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

From the project page:
This works by providing multiple options to control what should happen when the entity is being viewed at its own page. You have the ability to

Deliver an access denied page.
Deliver a page not found page.
Issue a page redirect to any path or external url.
Or simply display the entity (regular behavior).